# How to use Visual Studio 2017 with Qt to develop GUI applications?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, user-interface, visual-studio-2017

I have searched everywhere but I can't seem to find support for the latest Visual Studio version.

Is there some way of getting round this?

Comment: what kind of GUI application you are talking about? be specific

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Qt 5.9.1 and later versions are pre-built for VS 2017 64 bits. You can download it from [official Qt webpage](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/). If you need 32 bits I'm sorry to tell you that you will need to compile it manually (good luck, it is usually not a straightforward nor simple process). *See updates below*.

In addition, you will need the VS Tools. You can download latest version for VS 2017 from [here](http://download.qt.io/archive/vsaddin/) (official downloads page hasn't been updated yet about this). <s>There is no stable version for VS 2017 (*see update below*), but the latest (although a bit old) development build fixes major integration problems. You can downloaded from [here](https://download.qt.io/development_releases/vsaddin/).</s>

Finally, just take a look at the [official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtvstools/index.html) for a quick tutorial about how to use it. Basically:

- Configure your Qt version with the VS Tools: in VS go to *Qt VS Tools > Qt Options* and add your installation.
- You can now create a new project. The extension will add a new templates collection under Visual C++ called *Qt*, there you will probably use the *Qt GUI Application*.
- The rest is standard Qt programming. The VS Tools take charge of all the compilation of .ui files (interface design), moc'ing needed files, translations (if used), etc.

---

**UPDATE:** as mentioned in [this post from MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/03/07/binary-compatibility-and-pain-free-upgrade-why-moving-to-visual-studio-2017-is-almost-too-easy/), binaries generated usign VS 2015 are compatible with VS 2017. So in this case, the Qt compilations for 2015 (32 and 64 bits) should also work.

**UPDATE (2018-9-13):** since two months ago we've been using the 32-bits build from VS 2015 in VS 2017 (including the latest 15.8.4 update). No issues found so far in this sense.

**UPDATE (2018-12-10):** Qt 5.12.0 (LTS) comes with precompiled binaries for VS 2017 32 and 64 bits.

---

**UPDATE:** last February was launched the first official release of the VS Tools for VS 2017. You can read more on it [in the Qt's blog](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2018/02/26/qt-visual-studio-tools-2-2-0-released/).